# How to get the namespace of t4 template

Tags: namespaces, t4

I'm working on a code generation with T4 template. I'm generating multiple .cs files by one template and i need to write correct namespace for this files. Namespace depends on the template location. 
How can i get the template namespace for generated .cs files?
I know the only one way to do this - explicit setted property "Custom Tool Namespace" for the template and then get this property via EnvDTE assembly.  But this way is not ok for me, cause i need a locate a lot of copies this template for generate files in different propjects and i want to get namespace dynamically by the template location.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use EnvDTE's `FileCodeModel` to get the relative path of your template; and then use that to build your outputted namespaces?

You might want to browse through this post: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/walking-the-visual-studio-code-model-with-t4-template.html